# String cross product

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

Using:

```
digits   = '123456789'
cols     = 'ABCDEFGHI'
```

I want the output:

`["1A", "1B", "1C", "1D", "1E", "1F", "1G", "1H", "1I", "2A", "2B",
  "2C", "2D", "2E", "2F", "2G", "2H", "2I", "3A", "3B", "3C", "3D", 
  "3E", "3F", "3G", "3H", "3I", "4A", "4B", "4C", "4D", "4E", "4F", 
  "4G", "4H", "4I", "5A", "5B", "5C", "5D", "5E", "5F", "5G", "5H", 
  "5I", "6A", "6B", "6C", "6D", "6E", "6F", "6G", "6H", "6I", "7A", 
  "7B", "7C", "7D", "7E", "7F", "7G", "7H", "7I", "8A", "8B", "8C", 
  "8D", "8E", "8F", "8G", "8H", "8I", "9A", "9B", "9C", "9D", "9E", 
  "9F", "9G", "9H", "9I"]`

My code is:

```
def cross_prod(str_1 , str_2)
  res = []
  str_1.each_char do |a|
    str_2.each_char do |b|
     res << (a + b)
    end
  end
  return res
end

cross_prod(digits, cols)
```

Is there a better way to implement this method? In Python, it is about a line of code `[a+b for a in A for b in B]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This would work:

```
digits.chars.product(cols.chars).map(&:join)
#=> ["1A", "1B", "1C", "1D", "1E", "1F", "1G", "1H", "1I",
#    "2A", "2B", "2C", "2D", "2E", "2F", "2G", "2H", "2I",
#    "3A", "3B", "3C", "3D", "3E", "3F", "3G", "3H", "3I",
#    "4A", "4B", "4C", "4D", "4E", "4F", "4G", "4H", "4I",
#    "5A", "5B", "5C", "5D", "5E", "5F", "5G", "5H", "5I",
#    "6A", "6B", "6C", "6D", "6E", "6F", "6G", "6H", "6I",
#    "7A", "7B", "7C", "7D", "7E", "7F", "7G", "7H", "7I",
#    "8A", "8B", "8C", "8D", "8E", "8F", "8G", "8H", "8I",
#    "9A", "9B", "9C", "9D", "9E", "9F", "9G", "9H", "9I"]
```

Comment: Is there a way to use this &: operator with methods with parameters?

Comment: @GiorgioGambino maybe, could you be more specific?

Comment: I' m already done! Some reading about this &: operator cleared my ideas

Answer (score 3):

Stefan's answer is the way you *should* do it. However, simply for your edification I wanted to show you a way that works the same as your solution, but is more "Rubyish".

Generally speaking, in Ruby this is a code smell:

```
accum = []

some_enum.each do |item|
  # ...
  accum << result
end
```

When you see something like this (`accum` might be a string or an integer or anything else that can be "added to"), you can be pretty certain that your `each` (or `each_char` or whathaveyou) can be replaced with `map`, `reduce`, or similar. In this case (if we didn't have `Array#product` as in Stefan's answer) we could rewrite your code like this:

```
def cross_prod(str_1 , str_2)
  str_1.each_char.flat_map do |a|
    str_2.each_char.map {|b| a + b }
  end
end
```

Here we use `flat_map` in the outer loop. If we had used `map` instead we would have wound up with 9 arrays each having 9 elements.